# Bursted bubble like details on material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm trying to generate a material somewhat similar to what I got on a picture I took, just to develop material/texture creation skills, but I cannot get the details that appear to be tiny busted bubbles on the real photo.

I'm guessing this should be achievable using voronoi textures, but I cannot get even close to it. Can I get some tips to help me acheive that look here?

[image: Current setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: final]

You were pretty close.

I've used **Voronoi** for the bubbles and mixed it with some **Noise**.
First **Color Ramps** are for tweaking "contrast" of the textures and the last one is to give proper colours to the bubbles.

[image: nodes]